# How to use New Relic with ember-cli?

Tags: javascript, heroku, ember.js, newrelic, ember-cli

right now I'm running an ember-cli application on heroku by serving it with the `ember server` command (not sure if this is the best method) and I'd like to integrate it with New Relic, but I have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently removed my code from `<meta ...` in `app/index.html` and started to use this addon [Ember-new-relic](https://github.com/sir-dunxalot/ember-new-relic).

Answer (score 3):

Careful, `ember server` starts a live-reload server *for development purposes* — you edit a file, save it, and the application gets rebuild in an instant — you should **not** use it to serve an Ember app in production, it's a potential security risk. Normally you run `ember server` only on your local computer where you develop the code.

For production, build your app with `ember build --environment=production`, that will create a set of static files in your project's `dist/` directory. You can upload these as you would upload any HTML/CSS/Javascript.

Keep in mind that Ember (and other frameworks of this kind like Angular and Backbone) is a single page application (SPA) framework; there is no server-side code at all, it all runs in the browser. Usually you would provide some sort of API (like a REST-API) on the server to provide and process data from a database or to provide other server-side services. That way you can develop the front and back-end separately.

I'm not too familiar with New Relic, but as far as I can tell it is analytics software that runs on the back-end, so it has nothing to do with your browser-side framework.

Comment: I'm running `ember server --live-reload false --environment production` already, it starts an `express.js` server and `ember-cli` comes with a setup out of the box for me to create endpoints at any url I want, and it also get's rid of the # in the urls, I already figured out how to set up newrelic btw, but thanks.

Answer (score 3):

At the `server` folder, just find the `index.js` file and add `require('newrelic');` at the beginning of the file. Of course you should also follow the instructions when you setup New Relic at you Heroku App, setting your application as a node.js app, which means you'll have to run `npm install --save newrelic`, go to your `node_modules` folder, find `newrelic`, copy `newrelic.js` file to the root of your application and edit the file with your `app_name` and `license_key`.

Answer (score 1):

Get the [JavaScript snippet](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/browser/new-relic-browser/installation-configuration/adding-apps-new-relic-browser#copy-paste-app).

And add it below `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"...` in `app/index.html`.